# How to get address of ZwQuerySystemInformation from UserMode C++

Tags: c++, function, kernel

How can i get address of function `ZwQuerySystemInformation` in kernel from User mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it can help? "The NtQuerySystemInformation() API, which is exported from NTOSKRNL.EXE by name and therefore is as easily callable as ZwQuerySystemInformation() (ZwQSI) from a kernel-mode driver. The function is undocumented, so the necessary declarations must be specified and included first; otherwise, the linker cannot link the driver correctly." http://computervirus.uw.hu/ch12lev1sec7.html

Answer (score 1):

Use NtQuerySystemInformation instead.  You must use LoadLibrary() to get a handle for ntdll.dll and GetProcAddress() to obtain the address.  Beware that ZwQuerySystemInformation was removed from Windows 8, what effect that has on NtQuerySystemInformation is pretty unclear.  Clearly you'll need to test that thoroughly.